# check the array if it is empty or not that is received from the FORM that has CSRF generate token

Tags: php, laravel

Since I am using csrf in the form, the array `$data` that is passed in request function is never empty. 
How to resolve this so that when i submit the form without any input fields filled, I get "data is empty"?

**view.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{url('/userdata')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function userdata(Request $request)
{
    $data=$request ->all();
    if(!empty($data)){
        echo "data is filled";
    }else{
        echo "data is empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for replying. I have found a solution for this using Validator.

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    public function userdata(Request $request){
      $data=$request->all();
      $Validator=Validator::make($data,[
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'mobile' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);
        if ($Validator->fails()) {
          echo "data is empty";
   
        }else{
          echo "data is filled";
          
        }


    }

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misunderstood your question on my first answer. A value will always be submitted for input elements on the page, even if they're empty. The proper way to do this is to create a [request validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation).

Create something like this class, though much neater I'm sure ;)

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class StoreUserdata extends FormRequest {
    public function authorize() {return true;}
    public function rules() {
        return ["name" => ["required", "max:64"]];
    }
}
```

And then edit the signature of your controller method so instead of expecting a `Request` it looks for your validation class (don't forget a `use` statement above):

```
public function userdata(StoreUserdata $request){
// ....
}
```

Now, your requests will fail if the `name` input is empty, or is too long. There are [a lot of possible validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#available-validation-rules).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but it still prints "data is filled". $data = $request->except(["_token"]); did not work

Comment: Is the form field disabled or otherwise removed from the HTML? If not, the form input will always be submitted even if it's empty.

Comment: No it is not disabled.

Comment: Ok then your request will always have a `name` element, even if it's just an empty string. Are you trying to validate the request to ensure it always contains a value? There are better ways to do that.

Comment: I am trying to insert the datas into database, if the form is not filled and submitted, it still enters with null values. So i was wondering if its because of the csrf the array is never empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use required in the input fields if you don't want the form to submit empty.

```
<form action="{{url('/userdata')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Otherwise if name is your only field you can do this:

```
public function userdata(Request $request){
    $data = $request->except(["_token"]);
    if($data['name'] != ""){
      echo "data is filled";
    } else {
      echo "data is empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't rely on client-side validation for security.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get()` method:

```
public function userdata(Request $request){
    $data = $request->get("_token");
    if(!empty($data)){
      echo "data is filled";
    } else {
      echo "data is empty";
    }
}
```